# Секундомер на Android

Tags: android

Добрый день. Возобновил изучение платформы android. Возник такой вопрос. Есть два куска кода, вот собственно первый:

```
    public void runTimer(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final TextView timerView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int hours = seconds%3600;
         int minutes = (seconds%3600)%60;
         int secs = seconds%60; 
            String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,secs);
            timerView.setText(time);
            if(isStarting){
                seconds++;
            }   
        }

    }, 1000);

}
```

а вот второй:

```
    public void runTimer(){
    final TextView timerView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    final Handler  handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            int hours = seconds%3600;
             int minutes = (seconds%3600)%60;
             int secs = seconds%60; 
                String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,secs);
                timerView.setText(time);
                if(isStarting){
                    seconds++;
                }   
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Проблема в том что они должны, как я понимаю, работать одинаково, но работает только пример под номером 2. Кто знает почему так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 фрагмент кода вызывается ровно 1 раз. Он вызывается через 1 секунду с помощью `handler.postDelayed(..., 1000)` , отрабатывает  и всё.

2 фрагмент кода вызывается сразу методом `handler.post` и в конце своей работы вызывает `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` т.е. вызывает сам себе через 1 секунду.

А в целом рекомендую ещё посмотреть на класс `CountDownTimer`, который делает в принципе тоже самое, но "из коробки".

Comment: спасибо, я просто думал, что второй метод работает циклически с задержкой в секунду.